# Google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Пишу код по примеру, так вот в одном моменте устанавливают значения

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

метод getMap не видело. Поискав в интернете, понял, что этот метод изменили
на `getMapAsync(this);`
Теперь нужно писать так:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
```

Но у меня выкидывает ошибку.
Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.danilshik.testapplication.fragments.FragmentMapsShop.onViewCreated(FragmentMapsShop.java:76)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1439)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Application terminated.
```

Не пойму что является Null и как исправить
Источник: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323120/android-cannot-resolve-method-getmap`

Comment: Информации в вопросе недостаточно, но попробуйте заменить R.id.fragment_map на R.id.map.

Answer (score 0):

У вас возвращает null, потому что используется в классе `implements OnMapReadyCallback`

Callback'и выполняются после создания и отображения фрагмента. Поэтому вы должны использовать слушатель и прописать так:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}
```

Также не забывайте про проверку на null:

```
if (mMap == null) {
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
  }
```

this либо getApplicationContext()